# GDB Function Parameters is not shown

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

So I'm starting with using GDB. I'm trying out simple things to get used to it.

So I have the following code with a small bug in it. (Segmentation fault):

```
char *concat(char *s, char *t){
    return strcpy(s+strlen(s), t);
}

int main() {
    
    char *a = "Pliz, ";
    char *b = "Help me SoF";

    printf("%s + %s = %s\n", a, b, concat(a, b));
    return 0;
}
```

So it gives me a Segmentation fault.
When running `gdb main core`, and backtrace `bt` to display the program stack I get three frames. When looking at frame 1 of function `concat()`, I should see the two parameters `s` and `t` and their values. But I dont get to see it, How come? What I want is the following as in the picture (See desired result/view; The concat1.c is the same as main.c in my case).

[image: Picture of my terminal]

[image: Desired result]

Comment: Debug symbols are not present. You need to add `-g` to add debug symbols.

Comment: "But I dont get to see it, How come?" -- when asking a question, _show_ what you see, don't just describe it. This will generally produce better answers.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, Thank you for feedback. I have edited my question. I added the picture of what I get, and I added the picture of what I want to see.

Comment: Picture is better than a description, but picture of text is worse than the text itself (which you could have easily copy/pasted). In the future, please paste the text itself. (The answer by Krishna Kanth Yenumula is correct though: it's clear from your picture that you've compiled your code without `-g` flag,

Answer (score 1):

Here `a` and `b` are string literals. You cannot modify them. You are adding `b` at the end of `a` .This is the reason for segmentation fault. Visit this answer [Modifying string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-char-s-initialized-with-a).

Debug symbols are not present. You need to add `-g` to your compile and link commands to add debug symbols.